# firebase nosql about data structure for shopping cart

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, shopping-cart, nosql

I'm from relational database.
I would to build shopping cart application with friebase (Now I'm beginer GAE with NDB Datastore)
About
- product item
- order
- report

For report feature can see summary.
How many item sell and summary revenue of the month or year (by filters).
I don't know how can design to support this requirement in the noSQL that has no sum function.
Could you suggest me for that?

Comment: I don't know if this helps: https://github.com/arjunsk/ionic-firebase-shopping-cart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum firebase data efficiently up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838059/sum-firebase-data-efficiently-up)